# Vim jumping with <ctrl i> into another file doesn't work, works only within file

Tags: vim

Vim jumping with "ctrl i" into another file doesn't work, works only within file (naturally, there is a jumplist positions to another file).

"ctrl o" works in both within file and between files.

Nothing is remapping neither "ctrl i" nor "Tab" keys.

Any ideas?

Comment: We need more information to help you. Does this also happen in plain `vim -N -u NONE` (and which version)?! What's the output of `:jumps` before and after `<C-I>`? "Doesn't work" means no reaction, or beep, or what?!

Comment: Launching 'vim -N -u NONE' actually fixes the issue.

Comment: So, you do seem to have a mapping (maybe only in some buffers => check `:verbose nmap <Tab>`, or something is messing with your jumps.

Comment: I do actually have the following plugins installed: ctrlp.vim
dbext_2000
loremipsum
vim-sensible
vim-surround
vim-unimpaired
vimroom

Comment: `:verbose nmap <Tab>` says No mapping found

Comment: Hitting `<ctrl i>` sounds error bell

Comment: Removed dbext_2000 plugin, all is well. Seems it is the culprit. Wonder if I should ask here :"why dbext_2000 breaks stock vim C-I behavior in normal mode"?

Comment: Yes, and preferably ask the plugin's author, not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launching plain Vim with the factory-defaults lets you check whether a plugin is the culprit:

```
$ vim -N -u NONE
```

To troubleshoot Vim plugin problems, first check whether it is a problem on your side:

- Verify that the problem is not caused by your setup, by testing the plugin in isolation: Backup your `~/.vimrc` and `~/.vim` / `vimfiles` directory, clean it, keep / reinstall just the plugin itself.
- Maybe there's a newer version available by now. Check http://www.vim.org or the site from where you got the plugin.
- Try reinstalling the plugin or installing on a different system.

If the problem persists, contact the plugin author. He's best suited to help you, and most interested in bugs and fixes. His email is usually found in the accompanying documentation or header of the plugin.

Some older plugins are not maintained any more by the original author. An Internet search might bring up forks or alternative implementations. If there is none, the plugin's license (usually the Vim license or a common open source one like GPL or MIT) allows you to take over maintenance and start publishing your own versions. The community is grateful for this!